# Secondary lookup columns missing in Display/Edit form view

Tags: lookup-column, display-form

I have one list that has a lookup column for 4 different lists. Each lookup column also brings in a secondary lookup column which is a Calculated Column. I can bring both the lookup column and the secondary lookup calculated column in to my list for all lists. However, when I view an item, I can see the lookup column, but not the secondary calculated column.

I was able to do this exact same exercise with a different list and see the secondary lookup column in the View Item dialog box. I cannot use InfoPath to create a new display form, so solutions must be made OOTB or with SPD.

Comment: I think I may have an idea, I'll try to find time to test it today before posting to verify it. In the meantime, which version of SharePoint are you on?